# RHEL leapp upgrade inhibited by YUM

Tags: redhat, sap

i try to upgrade a RHEL 7.9 to 8.4 with leapp.
When i try the update, it stoppes cause it says that yum is missing the plugins

- product-id
- subscription-manager

But fun fact, when i start yum, it says that they are installed.

```
[root@hana2dev3 iteanova]# yum
Geladene Plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
```

I#m now stuck with the upgrade. Any suggestions?

Comment: redhat has a nice [tutorial](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/upgrading_from_rhel_7_to_rhel_8/index) howto upgrade from 7 to 8, specifically read the part for SAP Hana

Comment: i knew that tutorials and i#m following it. That's the problem. That leapp / yum behaviour is something that should not happen.

Comment: then I would suggest that you should consider to contact the vendor support.